# Customizing Elementary OS 5.1 Terminal Not Working

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-terminal

I'm tring to change the theme for default Terminal app, the commands seem to run without throwing errors, yet nothing happens.
I tried running:

```
gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings foreground 'rgb(46, 46, 46)'
```

also this bash script, but nothing takes effect:

```
palette="#121C21:#E44754:#89BD82:#F7BD51:#5486C0:#B77EB8:#50A5A4:#FFFFFF:#52606B:#E44754:#89BD82:#F7BD51:#5486C0:#B77EB8:#50A5A4:#FFFFFF"
foreground="#B3B8C3"
background="#121B21"
cursor="#E95420"
darkstyle="true" # true or false

gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings palette "$palette"
gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings foreground "$foreground"
gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings background "$background"
gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings cursor-color "$cursor"
gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings prefer-dark-style "$darkstyle"
```

**UPDATE:**

installing `dconf-tools` and setting the values from there works, but I'm confused as to why `gsetting set` commands aren't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only one correct way is to do this way:

```
sudo gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings background 'rgb(46, 46, 46,0.95)'
```

The last position 0.95 is about transparency. Less value means more transparent background.

Settings work only after the restart of the system, so each time you need to restart if you are changing values.

Comment: I did try that, it didn't work, I tried putting it in .bashrc, nothing changed either! so far nothing seems to take effect besides dconf-tool which btw doesn't require a reboot. But It'd be nice to get the command line command working, this wa i can write scripts for switching between multiple themes.

Comment: See this link. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141066/change-colors-for-the-pantheon-terminal-emulator Especially this one: http://mayccoll.github.io/Gogh/

Comment: Thanks @Sysadmin for referring this, it wasn't enough to work but has led me to the solution which I will post below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. I'll put it here in case someone faces the same issue.

First, I followed  @Sysadmin  [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141180/334880) mentioned in the comments above.

Then,

Run the following two commands in the terminal before trying to change colors or theme. (you can add this to your .bashrc or profile so that you don't have to do it everytime your system reboots).

`export TERMINAL='io.elementary.terminal'`

`export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/`

After this, you can run gsettings commands with no problem.

Also, this doesn't require a reboot and changes are reflected immediatly (pretty neat).

Check this awsome [tool](https://mayccoll.github.io/Gogh/) for switching themes easily.

source: [credits to drjmcauliffe](https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh/issues/175#issuecomment-534018420)